# Rails, Cocoon Gem - undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I am trying to setup cocoon gem for nested forms in my Rails 5 app.

Im having a problem that others have posted about, but it seems the solutions that worked for them are not working for me.

I have models for address, organisation and settings. The associations are:

Address

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true, optional: true
```

Organisation

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Settings

```
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

My settings controller has:

```
def setting_params
      params.require(:setting).permit( :newsletter,
        addresses_attributes: [:id, :description, :unit, :building, :street_number, :street, :city, :region, :zip, :country, :time_zone, :latitude, :longitude, :_destroy]
       )
    end
```

My routes are:

```
resources :organisations do
    namespace :contacts do
    resources :addresses
    resources :phones 
    end
  end

resources :users, shallow: true do
    scope module: :users do
      resources :assign_roles
      resources :identities
      resources :org_requests
      resources :profiles
      resources :settings do 
        namespace :contacts do
          resources :addresses
          resources :phones 
        end
      end 
    end
```

My address form has:

My settings form has:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @setting] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :newsletter, as: :radio_buttons, label: "Subscribe to our newsletter" %>

    <%= simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>
                <%= render 'contacts/addresses/address_fields', f: f %>
            <%= link_to_add_association 'Manage address', f, :addresses, partial: 'contacts/addresses/address_fields' %>    
        <% end %>   
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The error says:

```
undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class
```

This line is highlighted in the error message:

```
                <%= link_to_add_association 'Manage address', f, :addresses, partial: 'contacts/addresses/address_fields' %>
```

For others the problem has been using the singular instead of the plural; or using @addresses instead of :addresses (although some of the solutions have suggested its supposed to be @ instead of :.

I have tried each of these in each combination.

Can anyone see what I need to do to set this up?

**TAKING EDMUND'S SUGGESTION**

I can see from the simple form documentation that nested attributes should be handled differently in the forms.

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models#example-for-strong-parameters

I tried changing the form to:

```
<%= simple_fields_for "addresses_attributes[]", address do |f| %>
```

That doesnt work either. I can't render a page to inspect.

The error line in this context points to a problem with the new action in my organisation controller. That has:

```
 def new
    @organisation = Organisation.new
    @organisation.addresses_build
  end
```

The error message says:

```
undefined method `addresses_build' for #<Organisation:0x007fcf6ff25f08>
Did you mean?  addresses
```

I now wonder if I need to build address_attributes instead of address. But when I try I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `addresses_attributes_build' for #<Organisation:0x007fcf72c26d68>
Did you mean?  addresses_attributes=
```

Comment: Is your model `Setting` or `Settings`?

Comment: setting.rb     ................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write

```
f.simple_fields_for :addresses
```

The `f` refers to the form, and you need this to be able to iterate over all child-addresses.

And secondly, it is better to have the `link_to_add_association` outside of the loop (otherwise you can only add a new address if there already is one?)

So write something like

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>
  <%= render 'contacts/addresses/address_fields', f: f %>
<% end %>  
<%= link_to_add_association 'Manage address', f, :addresses, partial: 'contacts/addresses/address_fields' %>
```

(imho the example you refer to in the simple-form documentation is outdated and the elaborate form is not needed)

Answer (score 1):

This error is from Active Record. Here's documentation of this method in Rails 4.2.7. Shouldn't be a big change in Rails 5.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods/reflect_on_association

Cocoon is using that to identify the owner class of your polymorphic model. You can verify this by doing the following in your console.

```
Address.reflect_on_association(:addressable)
```

This will give you the polymorphic association reflection

```
Address.reflect_on_association(:setting)
```

This returns nil

And your `accepts_nested_attributes_for` relies on that method to find the children/belonging class. See source code here.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

And your form is nesting the address under settings. So it's not able to find the parent/owner class.

Comment: Okay but does that mean I need to do something to assign setting/organisation id to the addressable value in my address model? Im not sure what Ive done wrong to get this error.

Comment: @Mel I don't remember the exact syntax. but try `simple_fields_for :addresses_attributes`

Comment: Thanks. That doesnt work either. The cocoon docs say: f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task| - which is what I've done - but it doesnt work.

Comment: @Mel so the essence is, you need to use `addresses_attributes` as the field name in your html, instead of `addresses`. I personally don't have mush experience with cocoon in specific. but that's how you nest attributes for polymorphic models.

Comment: Thanks Edmund - I'll give it another go. There must be something that makes this work that I can't figure out - I'll start searching for ideas around your thought.

Comment: @Mel try to inspect the HTML that cocoon generates. you can post it here if you need more help

Comment: I can see from the simple form docs, that it suggests "addresses_attributes[]", address in the opening line: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models#example-for-strong-parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126771/discussion-between-edmund-lee-and-mel).